# How to make the below mentioned code more optimized and efficient

Tags: python, json

I am currently working on a json file shown in the below link

[JSON FILE FOR PRECIPITATION](https://api.weather.gc.ca/collections/ltce-precipitation/items?PROVINCE_CODE=MB&bbox=-107.314,50.82,-88.682,57.255&sortby=VIRTUAL_CLIMATE_ID,LOCAL_MONTH,LOCAL_DAY&f=json&limit=10000&offset=0)

The json contains data about precipitation recieved in a certain province  over several years ,starting from  1890 till 2023.The json contains two keys type and features.
Features is a list of dictionaries and in that we have the following keys
1.Geometry describes longitude and lattidue of location
2.Properties maintains precipitation record. These include
a) where the precipitation occurred.
b)What was the first highest rainfall,second highest,third highest ,fourth and fifth highest rainfall recorded in that location
c)Which year were these rainfall value recordedy
3Properties also includes details about the place where the data was recorded such as province name,idenitfier  and city code.

In all there are 123 year and what I am trying to do is maintain seperate dictionaries which tells us on that specific year  what are the highest values of rainfall recorded.

for example

```
for 2016 the following are the highest rainfall values recorded
12.7,  17.5,  23.2,  70.8,  14. ,  12.2,  22.6,  55.4,  34.6,
        30.2,  25.2,  37.6,  14. ,   5. ,  12. ,  46. ,  72.4,  32. ,
        40. ,   7.4,   9.6,  23.4,  27.2,  32. ,   4.2,  13.4,  24.2,
        48.4,  17.9,  31.3,  15.8,  22.8,  24.3,   4.4,  21.7,  32.6,
        32. ,  32.6,  16.1,  16. ,   3. ,  24.4,  87. ,  32.6,  46. ,
        25.7,  67.8,  11.9,   9.8,   9.8,  49.6,  29.8,   4.8, 303. ,
        11.8,  10. ,  19. ,   4. ,   7.4,  71.6, 245. ,  42. ,  59.2,
        25. ,   6. ,  22.9,  35.8,  28.9,  12.6]
```

The final dictionary looks like the one shown in below image
[image: output dictionary expected form]

Since I need to create a dictionary where key is year and value is list of all precipitation recorded.The following is the code I came up with.

```
"""
Open json file and read
"""
with open('items.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f)


"""
Extract properties from json
"""

X=[]
for feat in data['features']:
    climate_properties=feat['properties']
    X.append(climate_properties)
"""
record_precp is final output dictionary
record precp_year is list of all years 
"""
record_precp={}
record_precp_year=[]

for x in X:
    record_precpyear=x['RECORD_PRECIPITATION_YR']
    record_precp_year.append(record_precpyear)
record_precp_year=list(set(record_precp_year))

"""
1. iterate through all properties and for every year in record_precp_year  list if it's mentioned in the properties extract the preciptitation levels and create a new dictionary entry

this part of the code can be optimized.Can it be done in just two for loops?
"""
for x in X:
    for year in record_precp_year:
        
        record_level=[x['RECORD_PRECIPITATION'] for x in X if x['RECORD_PRECIPITATION_YR']==year]
        record_precp.update({year:record_level})
```

I feel that in last section could be optimized ,because if the json had more than 10,000 records then this code will become slow. Right now the total number of entries is limited to 5124 records.

As such if there is any way to optimize this code,please let me know.If you have any further clarifications about the data,please let me know.

Also,is it possible to plot the dictionary key against the list of values.I know there have been previous questions on this  particular topic  but they all deal with values whose size is either fixed or small.

For the plots this is my current code
Obtain  BOX PLOT For  record precipitation levels in 2016

```
precip_level=record_precp[2016]
precip_level=np.array(precip_level)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
bp=ax.boxplot(precip_level)
plt.show()
```

[image: Box plot for precipitation levels in 2016]

Comment: Use a library like pandas or numpy.

Comment: When you're just updating a single key in a dictionary, use `dictionary[key] = value` instead of `dictionary.update({key: value})`

Comment: pandas for obtaining the specific dictionary?

Comment: Pandas instead of a dictionary.